# foreach: grep backtick in for-loop

Tags: shell, foreach, grep, csh, backticks

How would one grep backtick from files in a for-loop.

I would like to run grep for a pattern '`define'. The pattern works in standalone grep command but fails in for-loop.

```
foreach xxx ( `grep -r '`define' $idirectory --no-filename | sed -e 's ; //.* ; ; ' -e 's ; #.* ; ; ' -e 's ; ^\s* ; ; ' | grep -v ^$ | sort -n | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -d`)
  echo $xxx
end
```

The backticks are conflicting in the for-loop.

regards

Srisurya

Comment: The issue here is not the grep line, it is the fact that the backtick is interpreted by the foreach. You would need to take the output of the grep and escape it in some way. I have tried and did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, don't use `'` and escape the backtick with backshlash.

So, the next didn't works:

```
grep -r '`def' *
```

and prints

```
No matching command
```

But this:

```
grep -r \`def *
```

works and prints

```
ewdwedwe `define`
```

So, simiarly for your script, the next works (file `btick.tcsh`):

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set greparg = \`def
foreach xxx ( `grep -l $greparg *` )
    echo ===$xxx===
end
```

and pruduces the next result

```
===btick.tcsh===
===btick1.txt===
===btick2.txt===
```

the content of btick.txt files:

```
btick1 `def`
```

Comment: Hi jm666, As I communicated earlier the grep in standalone works with the back-tick but fails in the for-loop. The solution you provided has the same result. ie passes in standalone but fails when used within a for-loop

Comment: @user1495523 added the script example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution.

Use of ASCII code for grep argument

```
 grep -rP '\x60define' $idirectory
```

where \x60 is the ascii code for "`"

Answer (score -1):

You should not use old and outdated back ticks, use parentheses like this `$(code)`
 
Try this:

```
for xxx in $(some code $(som more code)
   echo "$xxx"
done
```

Nesting and back tics makes it complicated, it need to be escaped. Compare this to:

```
listing=`ls -l \`cat filenames.txt\``
```

vs

```
listing=$(ls -l $(cat filenames.txt))
```

Comment: @copper.hat It may seem that CSH does not support parentheses, if so read this: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt (Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell)

Comment: Unfortunately I am all too familiar with csh. This is close to an impossible task in csh, and probably not worth the OPs time to look for a solution in csh.

Comment: @copper.hat I do agree, its better from OP to change to `bash` if possible.

Comment: @Jotne don't care about the downvotes, but probably because you answered an `csh` question with `bash`. The `csh` people are probably more _sensitive_... ;)